# After using git log to poke around a previous commit, how to return

Tags: git

Probably a simple problem here, but this is my use case:
Need to see something in old branch, run
`git log -10`

It tells me i'm not on any branch, so i run
`git checkout master`

However, after i checked out the previous commit, i can't seem to get back to the current one. I receive the message
`:$ git checkout master

Switched to branch 'master'

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 7 commits.

:$ git pull

Already up-to-date.`

How do i just go back to the current version of the master branch from that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look more closely at what git is telling you:

> Your branch is ahead of '**origin/master**' by 7 commits.

This means that your local repository has seven commits that have not yet been pushed up to the remote repository named origin. You don't need to do a `git pull`, you need to do `git push` to get your local and remote repositories synced.

Comment: Since these seemed to have worked for you, you should accept the answer :)

Comment: Um.. I did but it told me to wait 1 minute... then i went and did something else.